# ios boolean var declaration

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I declared a function with boolean input var. I get no errors. However, when calling it from another controller, notification appears: "incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending'BOOL' to parameter of type BOOL". What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
- (void)composeBar: (BOOL *)savePars
```

from other view:

```
AppDelegate *localFunction = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

[localFunction composeBar:YES];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`BOOL*` isn't a boolean. It's a pointer to a boolean. Just use

```
- (void)composeBar:(BOOL)savePars
```

You're likely confused because all Obj-C objects are declared with the `*`, but that's because they're actually pointers. However, `BOOL` is not an object, it's actually just a `char` which holds `0` or `1`. Just as you would use `int` for an integer instead of `int*` (or in more idiomatic code, `NSInteger`), you use `BOOL` instead of `BOOL*`.

Answer (score 4):

This is because you declared the function as taking a *pointer to boolean*, not a boolean. This is how the declaration should look:

```
- (void)composeBar: (BOOL)savePars
```

`*` accompanies *id types* (i.e. the ones you define through `@interface/@implementation`). Regular C types, enums, structs, etc. do not need a `*` in the declaration, unless you actually want to pass a pointer.